# Under what conditions is a battle a draw?

Tags: medieval-2-total-war

[The manual pg. 48](https://manuall.co.uk/pc-medieval-ii-total-war/) says that when the battle timer expires:

> As an attacker, there is a time limit. If you haven’t defeated the enemy before the timer expires, you lose the battle.

However, I have experienced a situation where the timer expired and the battle resulted in a "draw".  The manual doesn't mention this possibility, what might cause it, or what the repercussions are.

How does a battle end in a draw?  If I am defending a settlement, and a battle ends in a draw, what happens to the settlement?

Comment: Do you remember the general composition of your army/your enemy's army, or whether it was a field battle or a siege?

Comment: @Cadence At the time I observed the draw, I didn't pay it any mind.  However, now, later in the game with a gazillion wars going on all fronts, I'm much more interested in the mechanics.  tl;dr; no.  :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A draw is not possible in single player most of the time, only in multiplayer.

If the timer runs out in single player, the attacker loses the battle and must retreat. A settlement stays in the defenders hands.

The one exception is sallying out, due to the unique circumstance of the defender attacking and the attacker defending. If the timer runs out here, the battle ends in a draw, as the attacker doesn't want to retreat but hold up the siege, while the defender wants to keep the settlement. So, the status quo is maintained.

A multiplayer battle ends in a draw when the timer expires.

Comment: To add to this, I'm not sure if it was in  either Rome: Total War, Medieval II: Total War or both; but if a defender were to sally out and then retreat back inside the castle, provided all defender units are inside the castle and all attacker units are outside of it. The defender (player) can elect to end the battle, resulting in a draw and thus continuing the siege.

Comment: This is going to be IMMENSELY useful for sallying out my longbowmen to shoot up beseigers!